# Why can't this problem not be solved by allegation?

Tags: arithmetic, recreational-mathematics, ratio

Question:
"In the 75 litres of milk and water, the ratio of milk and water is 4:1. The quantity of water required to make the ratio of milk and water 3:1 is:_______"

My query:

I have tried a lot to comprehend into the matter but am not able to decipher into this. I tried applying techniques of allegation but only to know that it would not work.Is any definitive solution technique for these type of problems? If so what is that? A guidance about the same is most welcome. Also why is the allegation technique not working?

Comment: What does "allegation technique" refer to?

Comment: @Arthur Apparently it's a misspelling, and refers to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alligation): "Alligation is an old and practical method of solving arithmetic problems related to mixtures of ingredients..."

Comment: Ok, now that I know what alligation is, you say it didn't work for you. What exactly doesn't work? Could you show us your calculations? This way it's much easier for us to help you understand what went wrong and how you should correct it.